# S3 replication does not occur

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have a file under s3://bucket-name/dir/test.txt, and I only want to replicate contents under bucket-name/dir. I wrote down the following replication configuration. The replication does not occur. Does anyone know the reason?

```
    rules {
      id     = "replication_rule_id"
      filter {
        prefix = "dir/"
      }
      status = "Enabled"

      destination {
        bucket        = s3_destination_bucket.arn
        storage_class = "STANDARD"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to replicate files that are already there? Or when you add files they don't get replicated?

Comment: Also, what happens if you drop the trailing forward slash from the `prefix`? I.e, if you set `prefix = "dir"`?

Comment: @MarkoE I want to replicate files already there and also any other new files added later on

Comment: Just found out the above replication configuration only replicates files created after the configuration is in place

Comment: Yup, hence my first question. :)